# WCF Service Testing

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, testing

How can I test a WCF Service?

I tried soapUI, it works but I don't feel PRO when using third-party software when Visual Studio may have something to solve this problem.

I saw once, an web api stuff (don't really remember) that has a built-in client. And that was awesome!

Is there a way to have such a client on a WCF Service (file.svc) or test by adding some query string to the URL?

Something Like this:

http://localhost:56458374/Service.svc/Operation?value1=5&value2=6

Comment: Your webservice methods map to a class's method. You can simply instantiate that class in your unit tests and just test it as any other class.

Comment: What do you mean with test? Do you mean a client that you can manually try some interaction with your service, do you mean integration test or do you mean unit testing the logic? That three different scenarios with three different solutions.

Answer (score 2):

You can always open up a project (unit test project) and [add a reference to the WCF service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386382.aspx) - VS generates a fully functional client for you which you can then use for tests anyway you want.

Another option: Depending on the data types you use in the Service (not all are supported like Stream etc.) you can use the [WCF Test Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364.aspx).

Comment: In particular, create a unit test project to test the service.

Answer (score 0):

[WCF Test Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364.aspx) should you let you do that. In fact if you create a new project based on the WCF template. Hitting F5 will automatically do it

:

Answer (score 0):

I found once [this msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/dd939784) videos, when I start using wcf... there are also some cases how to test your services.